# Show Different Components using React-Native-Router-Flux Depending on Logged In Status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-native, react-native-router-flux

My app is using `react-native-router-flux` to decide which Component to show the user depending on whether the user is

- Logging in, or waiting for app to connect to backend *(show `<Loading />`)*
- Logged in *(show `<Home />`)*
- Not Logged In *(show `<Welcome />`)*

What is a recommended way to achieve that?

This example works perfect, except that it does not use `react-native-router-flux`. Anyway to modify the code to work with `react-native-router-flux`?

In my attempt below, calling `Actions.loading()` before the `render` function is called gives an error because `Actions` are not yet defined. Can the `if` statements be called after the `render` function?

Furthermore, everytime the props are updated, it causes a re-render of `App`, giving errors about how the scene keys already exist.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Meteor, { createContainer } from 'react-native-meteor';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import Home from './components/home';
import Welcome from './components/welcome';
import Loading from './components/loading';
import settings from './config/settings';


Meteor.connect(settings.METEOR_URL);


const App = (props) => {

    const { status, user, loggingIn } = props;

    if (status.connected == false || loggingIn) {
        // Render <Loading />
        Actions.loading();
    } else if (user !== null) {
        // Render <Home />
        Actions.home();
    } else {
        // Render <Welcome />
        Actions.welcome();
    }

    return (
        <Router>
            <Scene key="root">
                <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="Home" hideNavBar={true} />
                <Scene key="welcome" component={Welcome} title="Welcome" hideNavBar={true} />
                <Scene key="loading" component={Loading} title="Loading" hideNavBar={true} />
            </Scene>
        </Router>
    )
}


export default createContainer(() => {
    return {
        status: Meteor.status(),
        user: Meteor.user(),
        loggingIn: Meteor.loggingIn()
    };
}, App)
```

---

### Problem with using a `Dispatch` Component

Based on abeikverdi's suggestion, I created the following `Dispatch` component containing the logic to display one of the components `<Loading />`, `<Home />` or `<Welcome />`.

**Problem:** When `this.props.status.connected` is `true` (React Native app connects to Meteor backend), `this.props.user` is always `null` for a while before the React Native app receives this data from the Meteor backend. But because it is initially evaluated as `null`, `Action.welcome()` will have executed. This behavior is incorrect when `this.props.user` eventually becomes not `null` after a second or two and the user should have been redirected to `Actions.home()` instead.

Any ideas?

```
export class Dispatch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillUpdate() {
        if(this.props.status.connected == false) {
            Actions.loading();
        } else {
            console.log('meteor.user(): ', Meteor.user())
            if (this.props.user !== null) {
                Actions.home();
            } else {
                Actions.welcome();
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View></View>
        )
    }
}


export default createContainer(() => {
    return {
        status: Meteor.status(),
        user: Meteor.user(),
        loggingIn: Meteor.loggingIn()
    };
}, Dispatch);
```

---

### Errors/Warnings from logs `react-native log-android`

The following is the Android log output when the React Native app is started for a while before disconnecting it from the Meteor (DDP) server by killing the Meteor server.

Using `console.log("<App /> render")`, it appears that whenever the `render` function is called again after being passed new `props` by Meteor's `createContainer`, the `Key is already defined` error is triggered.

Anyway to get rid of this error/warning?

```
12-23 02:27:01.875 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "RNapp" with appParams: {"initialProps":{},"rootTag"
:1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
12-23 02:27:01.891 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: render
12-23 02:27:01.995 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Connected to DDP server.
12-23 02:27:01.999 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Connected to DDP server.
12-23 02:27:02.012 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: render
12-23 02:27:02.013 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key home is already defined!
12-23 02:27:02.013 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key welcome is already defined!
12-23 02:27:02.013 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key loading is already defined!
12-23 02:27:02.013 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key root is already defined!
12-23 02:27:34.592 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Disconnected from DDP server.
12-23 02:27:34.593 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Disconnected from DDP server.
12-23 02:27:34.599 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: <App /> render
12-23 02:27:34.599 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key home is already defined!
12-23 02:27:34.599 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key welcome is already defined!
12-23 02:27:34.599 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key loading is already defined!
12-23 02:27:34.599 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key root is already defined!
12-23 02:27:34.609 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: <Loading /> render
12-23 02:27:35.603 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Disconnected from DDP server.
12-23 02:27:35.613 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: <App /> render
12-23 02:27:35.613 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key home is already defined!
12-23 02:27:35.613 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key welcome is already defined!
12-23 02:27:35.613 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key loading is already defined!
12-23 02:27:35.613 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key root is already defined!
12-23 02:27:45.599 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Disconnected from DDP server.
12-23 02:27:45.616 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: <App /> render
12-23 02:27:45.616 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key home is already defined!
12-23 02:27:45.616 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key welcome is already defined!
12-23 02:27:45.616 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key loading is already defined!
12-23 02:27:45.616 31197 19338 I ReactNativeJS: Key root is already defined!
```

**`App` Component**

```
export class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.status.connected == false) {
            Actions.loading();
        } else {
            if (nextProps.user !== null) {
                Actions.home();
            } else {
                Actions.welcome();
            }
        }
    }


    render() {
       console.log('<App /> render')
        return (
            <Router>
                <Scene key="root">
                    <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="Home" hideNavBar={true} />
                    <Scene key="welcome" component={Welcome} title="Welcome" hideNavBar={true} />
                    <Scene key="loading" component={Loading} title="Loading" hideNavBar={true} />
                    <Scene key="profile" component={Profile} title="Home" hideNavBar={true} />
                    <Scene key="history" component={History} title="Home" hideNavBar={true} />
                    <Scene key="search" component={Search} title="Home" hideNavBar={true} />
                </Scene>
            </Router>
        )       
    }

}


export default createContainer(() => {
  return {
    status: Meteor.status(),
    user: Meteor.user(),
    loggingIn: Meteor.loggingIn(),
  };
}, App);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by using initial prop , you read from store the data that will indicate if user is logged in or not for example using access_token .

Then you use initial={access_token} // for example

But keep in mind that it'll show the last scene with initial prop equal to true

```
// in componentDidMount
const currentUserAccessToken = store.getState().currentUserAccessToken;
        <Scene
            component={SignIn}
            hideNavBar
            initial={!currentUserAccessToken}
            key="signIn"
            title={I18n.t('sign_in')}
        />
```

Comment: How can we handle the display of `<Loading />` component when the React Native app has not yet connected to the Meteor backend, and the situation where the user is logged out (externally from a website) he should be redirected back to `<Welcome />` asap.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a dispatch page and put your logic there. So just add Dispatch as a scene and then navigate from there.

```
return (
        <Router>
            <Scene key="root">
                <Scene key="dispatch" component={Dispatch} hideNavBar={true} initial={true} />
                <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="Home" hideNavBar={true} />
                <Scene key="welcome" component={Welcome} title="Welcome" hideNavBar={true} />
                <Scene key="loading" component={Loading} title="Loading" hideNavBar={true} />
            </Scene>
        </Router>
    )
```

**Update:** 
Seems like meteor is passing those arguments into props. Once the new props added then `componentWillUpdate()` wont be triggered. Instead you should put you navigation logic through `Actions` in `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` as follow:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.status.connected == false) {
        Actions.loading();
    } else {
        console.log('meteor.user(): ', Meteor.user())
        if (this.props.user !== null) {
            Actions.home();
        } else {
            Actions.welcome();
        }
    }
}
```

Then your navigation logic should be triggered after your login function is done. This should do the trick.

Comment: Updated my question about a problem encountered when using a dispatch page.

Comment: I see. I updated the answer based on your update. See if that works.

Comment: Thanks, doesnt having updated props cause the error about scenes keys already existing? I think subsequent calls to `render()` tries to create new `Scene`.

Comment: Whats the error your getting exactly? Its probably a router-flux issue your facing.

Comment: Just updated question with the `Key is already defined` error, and the corresponding code that uses your suggestion of using `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: Seems like somethings wrong in your router-flux. I cant see your full project structure. I recommend you to put your Router and scenes in the main first file. Create a scene for dispatch/splash and set `initial={true}` and do the rest from there.